# Rewrite url by htaccess in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to map url: I type on address bar the url http://help.localhost.com then I will see the page http://localhost.com/help.html, but the url on address bar isn't changed (still help.localhost.com). I used following code:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule "localhost/help.html" "help.localhost.com"
```

However, it didn't work for me.
Anyone can help me fix this!

Comment: I assume if you browse http://help.localhost.com directly you get the same content as http://localhost.com/help.php right ? If so, you can do something like: `RewriteRule ^(localhost.com/.*)$ http://$1.localhost.com [R=301,L,NC]`

Comment: Yes, absolutely right. But, html file, not php

Comment: What is the behavior when you directly visit `http://help.localhost.com/` in a browser?

Comment: same content with localhost.com/help.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?matheval\.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?help\.html$ http://help.matheval.info/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: It didn't work http://help.matheval.info (changed localhost.com into matheval.info)

Comment: What URL did you enter in browser?

Comment: I typed help.matheval.info, but browser notified that nothing. I can see the help page when typing matheval.info/help.html

Comment: It works, but wrong. It redirects from matheval.info/help.html to help.matheval.info only, and of course the address help.matheval.info didn't work. My purpose is that type help.matheval.info, but the result is matheval.info/help.html. And the address bar still present help.matheval.info